# Examples of groups that are not subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Sorry, my English is poor, but I have a question. It is usual to find the definition of subgroup as: "We define a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ to be a nonempty subset $H$ of $G$ such that when the group operation of $G$ is restricted to $H$, $H$ is a group in its own right". But it is known that $A=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & a\\a& a\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ with  } a \in R \mbox{ and } a\neq 0 \right\}$ is a group with the usual product of matrices but it is not a  subgroup of $M_{2\times2}$. Do you know another examples of subsets like this?

**Edit:** I'll try to change a little the question: In the set of matrices $M_{2\times2}$ there are subsets which are groups in regard to the usual matrix product but have a different neutral element. An example would be the group of all nonsingular matrices over $\mathbb R$,  $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ and $H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & a\\a& a\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ with  } a \in \mathbb R \mbox{ and } a\neq 0 \right\}$. Do you know of other examples of subsets (groups) with elements of the same nature, that given the same operation have a different neutral element?

Comment: Simply asking for more examples makes this question extremely broad and open-ended.  What exactly do you hope to learn from seeing more examples?

Comment: Identity $e=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{\pmatrix}$

Comment: Since other comments (since deleted) have claimed that $A$ has no identity, let me remark that $A$ does have an identity (the element with $a=1/2$) and is indeed a group.

Comment: Heh, a subset of a monoid $M$ may fail to contain ${\rm id}_M$ and yet still have its own identity element and be a monoid in its own right. Forgot about that tricky fact.

Comment: It is still the case that $M_{2\times 2}$ is not a group under multiplication.

Comment: Indeed, since $(M_{2\times 2},\cdot)$ is not even a group in the first place, can we really call $A$ a "subgroup" of that?  "We define a subgroup $H$ **of a group** $G$..."

Comment: OP never said $M_{2\times 2}$ was a group, and explicitly said $A$ is *not* a subgroup despite being a group with respect to multiplication.

Comment: Maybe this could be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension

Comment: @arctictern then what is this supposed to be an interesting example of? I mean $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group but it is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\cup \{1/2\}$. Who cares?

Comment: @DanRust Subsets of monoids $M$ that are monoids (or groups) with respect to $M$'s operation but fail to contain $M$'s identity element. The fact this phenomenon is interesting is precisely because it is counter to our initial intuition about identities and closure (as evidenced by the fact a few of us fell into the trap even here in the comments).

Comment: Ok I made a mistake with $M_{2\times2}$

Comment: I think we can lay this one to rest... If the OP feels inclined to edit the question in terms of monoids/semigroups they are welcome to, but it might be best to close/delete.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is a monoid and $X\subseteq M$ is a subset closed under multiplication, it possible for $X$ to not contain $\mathrm{id}_M$ and yet have its own identity element, even being a group. In particular, every ring is a monoid with respect to multiplication, like matrix algebras, so we can use them.

- If $R\oplus S$ is a direct sum of nontrivial unital rings, then $R^\times\times\{0_S\}$ fails to contain the identity element $1_{R\oplus S}=(1_R,1_S)$, but it is a group with respect to multiplication. In particular if these are matrix algebras $R=M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and $S=M_m(\mathbb{F})$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ then this is the group of all block diagonal matrix with $n\times n$ block an invertible matrix and all other blocks zeroed. More generally we can use $R^\times\times\{e\}$ with any idempotent $e^2=e$ in $S$.
- The ideal $(x)=\mathbb{F}x$ minus $\{0\}$ in the ring $\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^2-x)$.
- If $G$ is a group (or monoid really), we can adjoin a new identity $e$ to it, so that the multiplication table on $\{e\}\cup G$ extends that of $G$ with $eg=g=ge$ for all $g\in \{e\}\cup G$; then $G$ does not contain the identity element $e$.

Comment: The question contains an error, but today I learned a lot with the answers. Thank you

Comment: @wmora2 I see no error in your question. I think your question is fine. Some others had trouble seeing what features in the example you gave you wanted to see in other examples, and so found the question unclear. Even after it came to light in the comments what your question was about, it was closed. I assume its closure is part of a broader strategy to teach newbies to make their questions as clear as possible before asking so that they don't force commentators to wonder aloud about its meaning. Please don't be disheartened.

Comment: I understand your point. Me and several colleagues have gained in clarity with the question and answers

Answer (score 1):

The set of non-zero real numbers is a group under multiplication. As a subset of real numbers, it is not a subgroup under addition.

The subset, $\{-1, +1\}$ of integers is a group wrt multiplication but not a subgroup under the addition of integers.

All continuous maps $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ that are bijective form a group under composition of functions as binary operations. It is a subset of the group of all functions $[a,b]\to \mathbf{R}$ (this being a group under point-wise addition of functions). But not a subgroup.

Comment: I don't see how these are relevant. OP gave an example of a subset that is closed under the same operation but has a different identity element than the ambient algebraic structure. You're declaring that subsets of groups are not subgroups if we change the operation, which seems totally different.